# Should I and how do I create progress reporting in computation demanding algorithms in c++

Tags: c++

I am implementing some Deep Learning Neural Networks and existing code from Matlab normaly just prints out to the console such users have an idea of progress.

When I am doing my design for C++ and have put core parts of the algorithms into separate functions that I do not want to print stuff out to the console, are there ways or design principles for leaving a option to the users who use the algorithm to get some kind of progress indication?

Could one let a optional parameter be a function pointer that people could hook into, or how would I do this?

```
void my_heavy_algorithm(int * data, int n,...);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are exposing your algorithm as a collection of functions then the way to go would be to have one of the parameters be a function pointer with a signature like this:

```
void (*reportProgress)(void*, int)
```

But if you are designing your algorithm in C++ you should probably take advantage of encapsulation and create a class (or set of classes) for your algorithm. In this case you wouldn't want to add the function pointer as a parameter to the individual functions.

Rather you might make the function pointer a member of your class. And have accessor methods to get/set it. Or even better, provide an abstract class for reporting progress.

```
class ProgressReporter
{
    public:
    virtual ~ProgressReporter() = 0;
    virtual void notifyProgressChanged(void* source, int progressValue) = 0;
}

class Algo
{
    private:
    ProgressReporter* _userProvidedReporter = NULL;

    public:
    void set_ProgressReporter(ProgressReporter*);   // set accessor
    ProgressReporter* get_ProgressReporter();       // get accessor
    void my_heavy_algorithm(int*, int, ...);        // your algo. implementation fn.
}

void Algo::set_ProgressReporter(ProgressReporter* reporter){
    _userProvidedReporter = reporter;
}

ProgressReporter* Algo::get_ProgressReporter(){
    return _userProvidedReporter;
}

void Algo::my_heavy_algorithm(int * data, int n,...){

    // do stuff

    if(_userProvidedReporter != NULL)
        _userProvidedReporter->notifyProgressChanged((void*)this, currentProgress);

    // do more stuff

    if(_userProvidedReporter != NULL)
       _userProvidedReporter->notifyProgressChanged((void*)this, currentProgress);

    // so on and so forth..
}
```

Of course the above is a pretty simplistic example. If you expect your algorithms to support concurrency you should synchronize access to the internal user reporter and you might consider creating a base class for your algorithm and provide concrete derived implementations..

Comment: I can encapsulate my algorithm in a class. Is your ProgressReporter example to be the encapsulating class or should i include it someway in my class?

Comment: An example to illustrate what you mean in the last case would be nice.

Comment: The ProgressReporter is an abstract base class (equivalent to an interface) you would provide with your algo. class(es). Users of your algo. class(es) would be required to provide their own implementation of a class deriving from ProgressReporter that you would then use from the algo. class(es) to report progress..

Comment: I understand that, thats also what you wrote in your answer.  I dont understand how the interaction between my algo class and your ProgressReporter class is done. An example would be nice. Do you want the algorithm to be a method of the ProgressReporter? Or do you want me to do class MyAlgorithm : ProgressReporter, how does users inject their reporter into my algorithm?

Comment: No. Your Algo class is a separate class from the ProgressReporter abstract class. In your Algo class you would have a private member of type ProgressReporter and accessor methods which get and set this to an instance provided by the user of your Algo class.

Comment: okay. Like the answer below, just that the ProgressFeedback is not passed as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

STL style functors may help you. This would also allow yor algorithm be used withoud any progress indicator.

For example, let's say you'd like to give a percent progress indicator.

```
// disclaimer - I didn't compile this code
class NoProgressFeedback; // see below
void my_heavy_algorithm(int * data, int n, ProgressFeedback giveFeedback = NoProgressFeedback() {
    int percentProgress = 0;
    giveFeedback(percentProgress);
    /* start calculations, do stuff */
    percentProgress++;
    giveFeedback(percentProgress);
    /* continue over and repeat percentProgress updates and giveFeedback calls */
}

/* NoProgressFeedback will do no progress feedback */
class NoProgressFeedback {
public:
    operator()(int percent) {}
}
```

If user code wants feedback, then it should pass your my_heavy_algorithm function a different progress indicator, that sould look like this:

```
class GetProgressFeedback {
public:
    void operator()(int percent) { std::cout << "percent advance: " << percent; }
}
```

Comment: Will the compiler optimize the empty function call out ? or would it make sense to take a pointer instead and do if(giveFeedback!=0) giveFeedback->operator() ; ?

Comment: If you keep NoProgressFeedback class as shown, the operator() will be inlined, and it will be optimized-out AFAIK, because it's a NOOP.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Dependancy Injection.

You can pass an object that implements an IProgress interface. A NullProgress object could just have the stubs but does no real work for objects you aren't interested in monitoring.

The usual way is to run your computationally heavy work in seperate thread and use that to update a section of memory via a lock.  The UI thread then reads periodically from this memory location and updates the screen accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To report proper progress, you need three things:

1. An estimate of the total work to be done.
2. An estimate of how much work has been done so far.
3. A source of time.

You also need some way for your "heavy math" function to "report in". One way to do that is to have some sort of function that you call in the "start of function", "progress so far" and "end of function". The start of function also sets "total amount of work to do". Progress so far reports "how much is done now", and "end of function" says "I'm complete".

In a C++ class environment, this could be done as:

```
class Progress
{
    Progress() { };
    virtual void Start(int todo) = 0;
    virtual void Done(int doneSoFar) = 0;
    virtual void Finish();
};
```

This provides an interface that other classes can be derived from.

Of course, you still need to find a useful pace to put your "Done()" - if you put it too deep inside some tight loop, it will impact performance, but you need to do it often enough that it shows some useful progress too.